# Django save in two models with onetoone filed

Tags: django, django-views

I m beginner in Django and I have a problem and i can t resolve it

I want to save address to every person in a different model

I tried in this way but doesn t work

Sorry for my english

**`models.py`**

```
class Person(models.Model):
user - models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField("E-mail", max_length=50, blank=True)
address = models.OneToOneField(AddressPerson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class AddressPerson(models.Model)
domicile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
county = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
locality = models.ForeignKey(Locality, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**`views.py`**

```
def add_person(request):
address = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
person = PersonForm(request.POST or None)
if address.is_valid() and person.is_valid():
address.save()
person.save()
return redirect('myapp:add_person'
else:
address = AddressForm()
person = PersonForm()
context = {
'form_p': pacient,
'form_a': adresa
}
return render(request, 'person/add.html',context)
```

Comment: can you show `save()` of `AddressForm()` and `PersonForm()`

Comment: Why are you using a OneToOne field for the address?  I understand it for Person because you're extending User which is predefined in Django but you're defining both Person and Address and relating them with a OneToOne field so they make as well be the same table

Comment: every Person have a address in AddressPerson this is the reason that i have one to one field to AddressPerson